# Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.GetPageContent() return null

Tags: web8, api

`Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.GetPageContent()` even though page is available in Broker DB and `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.GetMeta()` is retrieving the values from Broker DB throwing null.

Am I missing any configurations? or any mismatch JAR files issue?
Same code is working while using old JAR files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was with the user's custom code rather than the Tridion product, configuration or implementation.

Answer (score -1):

In Application storage config  caused the issue.
Once I changed the value as  it started working.